# changing nodejs version through nvm is not persistent

Tags: arch-linux, node.js

I have two versions of nodejs (v10.15.0 LTS and v11
13.0 )  installed via nvm in my Arch Linux. Nvm keeps the LTS version as default so I had to change it to v11.13.0 to use it since I started my project with v11.13.0 . after restart ,  nvm changes it back to v10.15. So how do I make the change to 11.13.0 persistent.

edit: I use the command `nvm use [node version]` 
for example, `nvm use v11.13.0`

Comment: What command are you using to change the node version?

Comment: @DrZoo isn't it nvm use [node version]?

Answer (score 2):

Using `nvm use <version>` only uses the specified version for the life of the shell that the command was executed in. Once you close that shell, it will revert back to the default version.

In order to keep your version persistent with a version you want to use, you have to use the command:

`nvm alias default <version>`

I believe you can also use `nvm alias default stable` so it always uses the latest stable version.